# converting spaces into dashes

Tags: text-processing

Given a file with multiple lines, I want to change every space to dash.

I did like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    echo "${line// /-}"
done
```

This works just fine, but I need a better method!

Comment: FYI, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/38906

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The standard `tr` utility does exactly this:

```bash
tr ' ' '-' <filename.old >filename.new
```

You can use a tool like `sponge` to do in-place editing (hides the fact that a temporary file is being used):

```bash
tr ' ' '-' <filename | sponge filename
```

Comment: Here, no need for sponge, you can use `tr ' ' - < filename 1<> filename`

Answer (score 6):

```
sed --in-place 's/ /-/g' /path/to/file
```

Comment: `y/ /-/` works too.

Answer (score 3):

with perl:

```
perl -ne 's/ /-/g;print ' FILE
```

Comment: Bit weird to use `-n` to `n`ot `print` and then call `print` by hand afterwards. Why not just `perl -pe 's/ /-/g' FILE`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The answer is from 7 years ago. I have no idea about my answer; Your comment is definitely correct

Answer (score 2):

Use `-i` to have it write the changes to the file or the `-e` to have it just write the changes to stdout without modifying the file.

```
sed -i 's/ /-/g' filename
sed -e 's/ /-/g' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use replace.

```
replace " " "-" </path/to/file
```

Comment: I like to have my scripts be portable...  ;-)

Comment: In this case i prefer to use shell script for anything, using only shell commands so it can run in various kinds of jail shell. But the user wont like to use the while loop, as they say.

Comment: So `replace` is a script that you wrote? I've never seen it before. It certainly isn't a standard Unix utility and it's not available on the machines I'm using.  Oh, I found it! It's a Linux thingy? Cute.  ;-)

Comment: No isnt a shell script, im not trying to help with a shell script because the user wont to use shell script built-in command, but external tools like sed or tr, or replace! Its a external program that i think its very faster. I am giving +1 for you because tr is a very common tool in a lot of unix environments.  But i personally prefer to use pure shell built-in commands, even if the unix clans think it is a bad practice.